# Image not sized correctly when loading

Tags: android, image, picasso

I am using Parse (I know it's a dying service) to fetch and store images for me. Included in these are authenticated Facebook user's profile pictures. The pictures are 50x50. If I download the image locally, throw it in the drawables folder, and load it via XML (`android:src="@drawable/dummy"`) this is the result. It's what I want:

[image: Expected result]

But when I load the image from Parse and load it into the CircularImageView, this is the result:
[image]

As you can see, my head shrunk :(

Here's some code:

The CircularImageView in XML:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_list_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/dummy"/>
```

Loading the Image via Picasso Library

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(carItem.getUserPosted().getParseFile("profileThumb").getUrl()).noFade().into(viewHolder.profileImage);
```

Libraries used:

- [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)
- [CircularImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)
- [Parse (Baas)](http://www.parse.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picasoo has method called resize you can use it like that:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(img_url)
                .resize(img_width, img_heghit).into(image_view);
```

Comment: Perfect! Can't believe I missed that.